# Sending an email with a loop as body in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to send an email with different steps and values depending on what the user has edited on an image. For that, I'm using UserDefaults to save values.

Then I have the next code into an UIAlertController:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: .default)
        { action -> Void in
            //i is the last step register

            let nombre = alert.textFields![0]

            for n in 1...self.i {
                print("Step \(n): \(self.filterUserDefaults.string(forKey: "Step_\(n)")!)")
            }

            let filters = [
                "Brillo",
                "Exposicion",
                "Contraste",
                "Saturacion",
                "Saturacion_color",
                "Temperatura",
                "Blanco_Negro",
                "HUE",
                "Tintado_Rojo",
                "Tintado_Rosa",
                "Tintado_Naranja",
                "Tintado_Amarillo",
                "Tintado_Purpura",
                "Tintado_Verde",
                "Tintado_Azul",
                "Tintado_Marron",
                "Tintado_Gris"]
            for filter in filters {
                print("\(filter) = \(self.filterUserDefaults.float(forKey: filter).roundTo(places: 3))")
            }
            self.sendMail(filtro: nombre.text!, body: "XXXX")
        })
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    func sendMail(filtro: String, body: String) {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["blablabla@gmail.com"])
            mail.setSubject("Filtro \(filtro)")
            mail.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: true)
            present(mail, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("Error presenting email app.")
        }
    }
```

So printing is working as I expect but the problem is to put these prints into the body of sendMail function...

I tried:

```
            var steps: [String]?

            for n in 1...self.i {
                steps = ["Step \(n): \(self.filterUserDefaults.string(forKey: "Step_\(n)")!)"]
            }
            .
            .
            .
            self.sendMail(filtro: nombre.text!, body: steps!.joined(separator: "\n"))
```

But only the last step is written into the body's email and not the array...

Please, can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you need to initialise your array variable and use `append`

```
var steps = [String]()

for n in 1...self.i {
    steps.append("Step \(n): \(self.filterUserDefaults.string(forKey: "Step_\(n)")!)")
}
...
self.sendMail(filtro: nombre.text!, body: steps.joined(separator: "\n"))
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much!! Now the problem is that `separator: "\n"`doesn't make a new line... but that's another question, hahaha.

Comment: @Tsilaicos Hmm, it works in a playground. Maybe you need to experiment with using \r alone or together with \n

Comment: Epic fail from my side... it didn't work using email function due to I had set `mail.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: true)`... Solved using `mail.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: false)`. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

u can try out following code

```
var steps: String = ""
for n in 1...self.i {
steps += "Step \(n): \(self.filterUserDefaults.string(forKey: "Step_\(n)")!)"
}
```